# For loop just saves the final value in an array

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I'm fairly new with R and I can't get my head around a for loop. I've developed a big markov model based on a loop (now I know it's not the most efficient way but no time to change it now). the final outcome of the model is a pair of matrices for each value of one parameter j. A sample of what I'm trying to do is

```
for (j in 1:10){
  x<-3:13
  y<-rep(x[j],10)
  a<-matrix(y,5,2)
  y<-rep(2,10)
  b<-matrix(y,5,2)
  outcome<-array(0,dim=c(5,2,10))
  outcome[,,j]<-a*b

}
outcome
```

that is: saving in  the third dimension of the array the output of every loop. But as I see it saves only the last loop in the last dimension of the array. The model is much more complex so that I can't really change the basic structure but only find a way of saving its outputs. Any thoughts?
hope it's clear and any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: PS.  Stack snippets don't yet run for R code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `outcome<-array(0,dim=c(5,2,10))` from the loop! You're initialising the array to zero at each iteration; that's why all the matrices except the last one are zero. Put this *before* you start the loop and it will work fine.